# Empty background not showing up during page transitions - current page showing instead

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, navigation, transition

I'm working on a WP8 application. When i'm going to my settings page, the transitions (I'm using the WP Toolkit's Turnstile ones) play correctly, but while the next page is loading, the app displays the previous page again.

To make it clear, here's how it goes :

MainPage displayed -> Tap "settings" from the appbar -> NavigationOut transition animation plays -> **MainPage still on display** (should be a black - or white - background) -> NavigationIn transition animation plays -> Settings page displayed.

It's really ugly and makes the whole app completely clumsy.

I feel like I'm the first one that ever had this problem on the whole internet, as I can't find any info. So I must have messed up somewhere, right ? But the more I'm looking, the more everything seems correct.

The only modification I made on App.xaml.cs is replacing the RootFrame type by a TransitionFrame :

```
//RootFrame = new PhoneApplicationFrame();
RootFrame = new TransitionFrame();
```

I did include the toolkit in my xaml pages...

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

... and right after the closing tag :

```
<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardIn" />
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardIn" />
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
    </toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardIn" />
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardIn" />
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
    </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
```

in both MainPage.xaml and Settings.xaml.

I'm navigating the most classic way possible, with the click event on my settings menu item :

```
private void settings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Settings.xaml", UriKind.Relative));   
    }
```

So... I'm pretty much out of ideas. Am I making an obvious mistake here ? Would any of you have the slightest idea of where it could come from ?

If you need any more information, just ask, I'll be as precise as possible. Thanks in advance !

Comment: So I must understand that the transition is working but it is ugly right?

Comment: The In and Out transitions are both working fine : the problem is, while the settings page is loading, the main page shows up again,  **after** its own out transition. Which pretty much ruins the purpose of having one. The usual behavior would be having an empty background in between instead of still displaying the previous page.

Comment: Simply show a popup that has the size of the screen in whatever color you want. This should be shown after the transition out. And removed the popup before transition in animation.

Comment: Have you set for both pages the `Turnstile Transition`?

Comment: @JTIM : I don't really like this solution. I guess it could work, but that's (literally) hiding the problem, leaving the bug untouched. I'm trying to understand why it's not working like it does for everyone else.

Comment: I do not know how others do and I do not use these animations in my projects. It was simple solution :) how somebody else can help you them.

Comment: Actually I am having the opposite of your problem. When I have my transitions it looks so empty and I'd like to show some kind of an empty page that has the colourfull bars that all other views have as a background..

Maybe your problem is in the App.xaml.cs? `RootFrame = new TransitionFrame();` and stuff?